# Implementing a C# interface in a VB class

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll, plugins

I am working on a plugin architecture and after some reading I have settled on one. The host class will be implemented in C# as well as some of the plugins for that host. The issue I am having is that some of my team uses VB.net. So the question, is it possible to implement a C# (plugin)interface in VB, such that when it is dynamically loaded into the host program it will have the methods required by the interface.

The idea I am attempting in VB:

```
Imports PluginInterface 

Public Class Class1 Implements IPlugin


End Class
```

Note: PluginInterface is the namespace that contains the C# IPlugin interface

Comment: I did try the code above unfortunately the namespace can not be found. The example I am modeling this after can be found codeproject.com/KB/cs/pluginsincsharp.aspx . I am trying to implement the given C# Iplugin interface in a VB class, like above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely implement an interface written in C# within VB.NET, and vice versa.